# Run a script on anaconda prompt in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, anaconda

I want to run the following script on my windows anaconda prompt.

```
conda deactivate
conda create -n keras_env python anaconda
conda activate keras_env
conda install -n keras_env keras pydot graphviz tensorflow theano scikit-learn mkl
```

But when I write a .bat file and run it, it doesn't do  anything at all. It doesn't even produce an error message. But it works quite well when I type in each line one by one manually. How do I put these commands in a script so that they can be run at once?

Comment: `conda` is really a batch file, so given that important fact you need to `Call` it!

Comment: When creating an env put everything in a YAML file and run `conda env create -f my_env.yaml`. It is always better to let Conda solve everything from the start than to iteratively install.